# How do you create Stack Overflow-style Up-Down arrows?

Tags: jquery, html, css, vote-up-buttons, updown

I am trying to create vote up and down arrows similar to what exists here on Stack Overflow. Ideally I'd like to have them interact dynamically with a piece of text recording the number of votes, just as they do on Stack Overflow.

Comment: What have you got so far?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless there's some trick I hadn't considered, I'd think you'd need to create a many-to-many relationship between users and the items being voted on.

Every time someone votes up or down, you'd add a record to the joining table. This is the only way I see to track which user has already voted and be able to track both the number of up and down votes--like stackoverflow does.

Answer (score 0):

you should look toward ajax technology in javascript to store the number of votes without page refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Not enough with jQuery + HTML only. You need extra ingredients like PHP and MySQL to save the votes.

**[Example](http://www.9lessons.info/2009/08/vote-with-jquery-ajax-and-php.html)** how to make voting system with jQuery, PHP & MySQL.